# Checkbox on a listView prevents event click, kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, kotlin, onclicklistener

**Using kotlin**

Hi, I'm doing a listview with title, description and a checkbox.

Without the checkbox, when I click the cell, it opens a detailsActivity about the item.

So I have added a checkbox, with its default check action to make the user capable of select items, and it seems like it is preventing the view click event.

```
  listView.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, position, id ->
        val productListToDetail = Intent(this, ProductDetailActivity::class.java)
        productListToDetail.putExtra("title",platoList[position].nombre)
        productListToDetail.putExtra("descripcion",platoList[position].descripcion)
        startActivity(productListToDetail)
    }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these properties to your `CheckBox`:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: I'm really introducing myself to android, i supose this was a newbie stone  Thank you so much!

Comment: Yeah, I think this is a common question for newbies, you're welcome :)